# Do subsets cancel each other out?

Tags: r, vector

I've only started learning R a few days ago.

Do subsets cancel each other out because if I do x[1:4] <- x[1:4], it will yield 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 instead of 11, 22, 33, 44.

```
x <- c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55)
x[1:4]
x

x[1:4] <- x[1:4]
x
```

Comment: What does "Do subsets cancel each other out" mean? Please study `?Extract`. Carefully. And again ;) It's among the top-n most important help pages, where n is very small.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
x[1:4] <- x[1:4]
```

Does nothing.  The output is as expected.  Put into natural language, the statement reads "Assign new values to elements 1 to 4 of the vector x."  (That's the `x[1:4] <-` bit.) "The new values should be taken from elements 1 to 4 of the vector x."  (That's the second `x[1:4]`.  In other words, "do nothing".

It's not clear what you are trying to do, but if the expected output is 11, 22, 33, 44, then this could be done by

```
x <- x[1:4]  # Keep elements 1 to 4
```

or

```
x <- x[1:4]  # Drop element 5
```